# linux: talk command not working

Tags: command-line, networking

***-- Setup --***

user - anuraag
Machine A - 10.1.192.217

user - anuraag
Machine B - 10.107.2.210, 10.107.2.55, 10.107.2.217

talk is installed in both the machines,

***-- Problem --***

when i type:

> talk anuraag@10.107.2.210

on Machine A, I get

> [Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
>
> ---

and after pressing any key, the window closes.
same thing happens when i try:

> talk anuraag@10.1.192.217

on Machine B

can someone help me here, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What does `mesg` display on the B host?

Comment: On both machines, mesg command gives "is y"